# PhantomJS not logging in using PHPSESSID cookie

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, webkit, phantomjs

I would like to use my PHPSESSID cookie from a certain website to use the session in PhantomJS v1.9.1

For example, say I want to load a website in PhantomJS, e.g. http://example.com. And I want to use the site's PHPSESSID cookie from my Chrome browser (where I am already logged in) in PhantomJS, in order to be logged there with the same session.

For some reason, however, it does not seem to work.

I am sure the website uses PHPSESSID cookie since I checked the cookies from the Chrome dev console. I also use the exact value from there.

Here is my code:

```
phantom.addCookie({
    'name':     'PHPSESSID',
    'value':    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'domain':   'example.com'
});

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36";
page.open('http://example.com', function () {
    page.render('screenshot.png');

    for(var i=0; i<phantom.cookies.length; i++)
        console.log(phantom.cookies[i].name+" = "+phantom.cookies[i].value);

    phantom.exit();
});
```

Please note that I have changed the cookie value to 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' and the website to 'example.com' for security reasons.

I have tested the script with other sites as well (copying the respective PHPSESSID values), didn't work even once.

It also takes a screenshot, which reveals the login screen (not the welcome screen).

I also print out all the `phantom.cookies` and the PHPSESSID is there!

Why doesn't it work? Am I doing something wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: You want to read other domains cookies? Do you know about security?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clearer on what I want to achieve.